# How can I move each object in his turn using time to start each object to move?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The goal is to use a time variable for example if the variable int value is 5 then each 5 seconds another object will start moving on the positions.

Now with the loop inside the Move method :

```
for (int i = 0; i < objectsToMove.Count; i++)
```

All the objects are moving at the same time but I want to make some kind of queue logic so each N seconds another object will start moving on the positions.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveOnCurvedLines : MonoBehaviour
{
    public LineRenderer lineRenderer;
    public List<GameObject> objectsToMove = new List<GameObject>();
    public float speed;
    public bool go = false;
    public bool moveToFirstPositionOnStart = false;

    private Vector3[] positions;
    private Vector3[] pos;
    private int index = 0;
    private bool goForward = true;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        objectsToMove = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("New Prefab").ToList();

        pos = GetLinePointsInWorldSpace();

        if (moveToFirstPositionOnStart == true)
        {
            objectsToMove[0].transform.position = pos[index];
        }
    }

    Vector3[] GetLinePointsInWorldSpace()
    {
        positions = new Vector3[lineRenderer.positionCount];
        //Get the positions which are shown in the inspector 
        lineRenderer.GetPositions(positions);


        //the points returned are in world space
        return positions;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (go == true)
        {
            Move();
        }
    }

    void Move()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < objectsToMove.Count; i++)
        {
            Vector3 newPos = objectsToMove[i].transform.position;
            float distanceToTravel = speed * Time.deltaTime;

            bool stillTraveling = true;
            while (stillTraveling)
            {
                Vector3 oldPos = newPos;
                newPos = Vector3.MoveTowards(oldPos, pos[index], distanceToTravel);
                distanceToTravel -= Vector3.Distance(newPos, oldPos);
                if (newPos == pos[index]) // Vector3 comparison is approximate so this is ok
                {
                    // when you hit a waypoint:
                    if (goForward)
                    {
                        bool atLastOne = index >= pos.Length - 1;
                        if (!atLastOne) index++;
                        else { index--; goForward = false; }
                    }
                    else
                    { // going backwards:
                        bool atFirstOne = index <= 0;
                        if (!atFirstOne) index--;
                        else { index++; goForward = true; }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    stillTraveling = false;
                }
            }

            objectsToMove[i].transform.position = newPos;
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I tried with InvokeRepeating :

Starting InvokeRepeating in the Start() and cancelled the Move() calling in the Update.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveOnCurvedLines : MonoBehaviour
{
    public LineRenderer lineRenderer;
    public List<GameObject> objectsToMove = new List<GameObject>();
    public float speed;
    public bool go = false;
    public bool moveToFirstPositionOnStart = false;

    private Vector3[] positions;
    private Vector3[] pos;
    private int index = 0;
    private bool goForward = true;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        objectsToMove = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("New Prefab").ToList();

        pos = GetLinePointsInWorldSpace();

        if (moveToFirstPositionOnStart == true)
        {
            objectsToMove[0].transform.position = pos[index];
        }

        InvokeRepeating("Move", 3f, 0.1f);
    }

    Vector3[] GetLinePointsInWorldSpace()
    {
        positions = new Vector3[lineRenderer.positionCount];
        //Get the positions which are shown in the inspector 
        lineRenderer.GetPositions(positions);


        //the points returned are in world space
        return positions;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (go == true)
        {
            //Move();
        }
    }

    void Move()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < objectsToMove.Count; i++)
        {
            Vector3 newPos = objectsToMove[i].transform.position;
            float distanceToTravel = speed * Time.deltaTime;

            bool stillTraveling = true;
            while (stillTraveling)
            {
                Vector3 oldPos = newPos;
                newPos = Vector3.MoveTowards(oldPos, pos[index], distanceToTravel);
                distanceToTravel -= Vector3.Distance(newPos, oldPos);
                if (newPos == pos[index]) // Vector3 comparison is approximate so this is ok
                {
                    // when you hit a waypoint:
                    if (goForward)
                    {
                        bool atLastOne = index >= pos.Length - 1;
                        if (!atLastOne) index++;
                        else { index--; goForward = false; }
                    }
                    else
                    { // going backwards:
                        bool atFirstOne = index <= 0;
                        if (!atFirstOne) index--;
                        else { index++; goForward = true; }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    stillTraveling = false;
                }
            }

            objectsToMove[i].transform.position = newPos;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try ```InvokeRepeating()```? This might be the solution that you are looking for.

Comment: @Ankit I tried now in the Start InvokeRepeating("Move", 3f, 0.1f); instead calling Move() in the Update. But the prefabs are not moving at all or too slow and not sure if they move one by one as I wanted. I didn't change anything inside the Move method.

Comment: Can you please update your code in question?

Comment: @Ankit Updated my question with the code I tried.

Comment: Let me Update your code a bit

Comment: Check my answer I made some changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 0;
void StartMove()
{
    i = 0;
    InvokeRepeating(nameof(Move), 3f, 0.1f);
}
void Move()
{
    if( i < objectsToMove.Count)
    {
        Vector3 newPos = objectsToMove[i].transform.position;
        float distanceToTravel = speed * Time.deltaTime;

        bool stillTraveling = true;
        while (stillTraveling)
        {
            Vector3 oldPos = newPos;
            newPos = Vector3.MoveTowards(oldPos, pos[index], distanceToTravel);
            distanceToTravel -= Vector3.Distance(newPos, oldPos);
            if (newPos == pos[index]) // Vector3 comparison is approximate so this is ok
            {
                // when you hit a waypoint:
                if (goForward)
                {
                    bool atLastOne = index >= pos.Length - 1;
                    if (!atLastOne) index++;
                    else { index--; goForward = false; }
                }
                else
                { // going backwards:
                    bool atFirstOne = index <= 0;
                    if (!atFirstOne) index--;
                    else { index++; goForward = true; }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                stillTraveling = false;
            }
        }

        objectsToMove[i].transform.position = newPos;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Try this one might help you. Here What I did is to remove the `for()` loop and instead use an `if()` condition this way You move function will only execute one time only for one object each time `Move()` get called by `InvokeRepeating()`. Nove Call `StartMove()` where/when you want to start moving the objects.

Comment: The objects are not moving at all. I tried calling StartMove from inside Start() like this InvokeRepeating("Move", 0.5f, 0.1f); Tried also InvokeRepeating("Move", 3f, 0.1f); or InvokeRepeating("Move", 0.5f, 3f); but the objects are not moving at all. I also tried like you did InvokeRepeating(nameof(Move), 3f, 0.1f); but nothing is moving.

Comment: Can you tell me what is the output/outcome of your original code?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply I was a bit busy.